# on to many inverse process

Tags: swift, core-data

I stored data in core data as one-to-many relationship, where one is the parent and many are children 
How can I know if I have the child which parent is related to it?
I know how to fetch children from parents but I want the inverse process.
Here is the code for saving data

```
let parent = DataController.saveParent(parentData)
let child = DataController.saveChild(ChildData) 
parent.setValue(NSSet(object: child), forKey: "childR")
try? parent.managedObjectContext?.save()
```

Here how i fetch parent from child

```
let context = DataController.getContext()
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Parent> = Parent.fetchRequest()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentR == %@", child!)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
print(try! context.fetch(fetchRequest))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an Inverse Relationship:

- Entity `Parent`:

  To Many Relationship: `children`, Destination : `Child`, Inverse: `parent`

  Property in the NSManagedObject subclass:

  ```
  @NSManaged var children: Set<Child>
  ```
- Entity `Child`:

  To One Relationship: `parent`, Destination: `Parent`, Inverse: `children`

  Property in the NSManagedObject subclass:

  ```
  @NSManaged var parent: Parent
  ```

Comment: can you clarify it more, i can't get it

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: thanx for the update, but that what i did. the point how to know the parent if i have the child

Comment: There's no need to fetch something, just get the `parent` value from the property.

Comment: wow! really thank you, it is very simple. I just was over thinking :)